# How to run rqlite as a service?

Tags: linux, service

Can [rqlite](https://github.com/rqlite/rqlite) run as a Linux service? so it can be start/stop/restart with systemctl command. Any example of the service file would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic systemd service file with `ExecStart` set to your `rqlited` command should suffice. See example below.

A more thorough service file can be found in the very good [Arch User Repo package of rqlite](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rqlite/).
It also includes creation of rqlite system user and directory and more security considerations.

Information on how to form a cluster with `rqlite` started as a service can be found [on XenGi, the packager's page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/User:XenGi#Installation). It makes use of an environment file that sets the arguments of `rqlite` nodes.

```ini
[Unit]
Description=
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rqlited -http-addr 0.0.0.0:4001 -raft-addr 0.0.0.0:4002 /path/to/datadir
User=youruser
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillSignal=SIGTERM
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thank you, @popo it's very helpful!